# Copying integer to integer with allocated memory

Tags: c, memory-management, copy, integer, strncpy

I have a problem with the code below.

```
...
int anInteger;
...
//anInteger gets a value
...

int *anotherInteger;
label = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
strncpy(anotherInteger, anInteger, 40);
```

Essentially what I want to do is to copy the value from an integer to my other integer which I have allocated memory for. Can this work with strncpy between integers or do I need another function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just dereference `anotherInteger`.

```
*anotherInteger = anInteger;
```

`strncopy` is for strings.

Comment: `anotherInteger = malloc(sizeof *anotherInteger); *anotherInteger = anInteger` is the right approach.  Note: I find `strncpy()` better suited for array of `char` more so than C strings.  The result of `strncpy()` may not be a string, just a modified array of `char` with no terminating `'\0'`.